# Displaying Bitmaps sequentially, "like a video"

Tags: android, bitmap, ffmpeg

I'm trying to reproduce a video that is not android supported (like a .wmv video) in my app, and actually I'm able to grab every frame and create a Bitmap of it.

So, now, I'm trying to show those bitmaps in a VideoView (or any other view), sequencially, something like a video.

Some code:

```
while (true) {
                frame = frameGrabber.grab();
                if (frame == null)
                    break;
                frame2 =
                        IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(),
                                opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
                opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(frame, frame2,
                        opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2RGBA);

                bm =
                        Bitmap.createBitmap(frame2.width(),
                                frame2.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(frame2.getByteBuffer());
                canvas = new Canvas(bm);
                mVideoView.draw(canvas);
                canvas.save();
```

It looks like I can grab every frame of the video (using ffmpeg), but I just don't know how to display them.

By the way, I've already tried encoding this video to a .mp4 file and playing it on the VideoView, but it takes much time to process the whole video (1 hour), so, now, I'm trying to display it right away, without encoding it do .mp4 (or any other android supported video)

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AnimationDrawable . it will work.

Little bit documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use FFplay to play back your image sequence live.  You wouldn't need to encode it to a video file first.

Say your files were named image1.bmp, image2.bmp, image3.bmp ... etc  and you wanted to play them back at 30 frames per second, try:

`ffplay -framerate 30 -i image%d.bmp`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your problem.

Now that your canvas is filled (assuming it is correctly filled), you can draw it on a SurfaceView by calling its draw(Canvas) method.

I'm curious about the result though, because if it takes you so much time to encode the complete video, it could mean your encoding is very long, so you might have serious framerate problem (or maybe the video is extremly long?).